# How to get ng-packagr to generate source maps

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I made an Angular app with Angular CLI and added some packagr files to it. When I run pacakgr no source maps are generated to the dist folder. How do I make that happen? I have enabled them in tsconfig.json, which is all I would expect to do.

Here is a simple repo that demonstrates the problem:

```
git clone https://github.com/philipbeber/packagr-example.git
cd packagr-example
npm install
npm run packagr
```